# Wiring for cutom USB cables

Tags: usb, wiring, computers

I am working on DIY-ing a handful of USB cables (USB-A to mini for PC peripherals and phone charging), and I'd like a professional take on two dilemmas that I have:

1) I have the option of using either 28AWG tinned copper wires throughout (for both power and data), or the option to use 28AWG for the data and 24AWG for the power. The 28/24 seems like the better way to go (more power = faster charging), but I'm not sure if that would cause trouble in any way. In either case, the four internal wires would be wrapped in foil and shielded in a tinned copper braided shield.

2) Also, the wire I have found is rated at 300v. I know USB ports typically put out only 5v...so is a 300v capacity wire trouble? Or is that irrelevant?

Thanks so much in advance. All the best!

Comment: what kind of peripherals?

Comment: (background of that question: for low-rate applications and charging, the high-frequency properties of the cable you use doesn't matter. It does, however, matter, should you try to transmit gigabytes of data)

Comment: Are you sure you want USB-A to mini-usb? Very few modern devices use mini-usb.

Comment: USB is very picky about the properties of the wires you use for data. Simply wiring D+ to D+ and D- to D- is not good enough. It's at least as 'finicky' as Ethernet.

Comment: Why diy. Cheaper and higher quality to buy dollar store special.

Answer (score 1):

1. If it's not too much more expensive, the thicker power cables are the way to go.
2. It's irrelevant. The only problem here would be if the wire was rated for too *low* a voltage; too *high* is fine.